# Filtering alphabetic characters in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to filter out only alphabetic characters from a collection. For example, I want only the characters `A` `B` `c` `d` from `"A(B%$c32d"`. Is using regular expressions the only way?

Comment: regexes are pretty good dealing with strings. The first two answers I see (using filter) all deliver a sequence of char, while (clojure.string/replace "A(B%$c32d" #"[^a-zA-Z]" "") will just return a string. A function meant to deal with strings, why don't you like it?

Comment: @AssenKolov that's also a nice solution, your comment could be an answer.

Comment: @Assen Kolov Thanks. I was just curious to see if there is also another method of doing this kind of filtering without using regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest implementation I can think of:

```
(filter (fn [x] (Character/isLetter x)) "abc")
```

It uses the Java static function `Character.isLetter`.

Comment: also, one can throw in `(apply str ...` to get another string back as the final value

Answer (score 10):

In Clojure :

```
(apply str (filter #(Character/isLetter %) "abc:sQ/SDQ_"))
;; "abcsQSDQ"
```

In Clojure and ClojureScript, using a regex :

```
 (apply str (re-seq #"[a-zA-Z]" "abc:sQ/SDQ_"))
```

Comment: Re: regex solution: \w is the character group of word characters, which also includes numbers and _. `filter` changes the string to a seq of characters, and regexes cannot be applied to characters, so it fails.

Comment: There's also `Character/isLetterOrDigit`

Comment: @BHBH yes, as well as all the Java functions out there :)

Answer (score 5):

Using regex this is another solution:

```
(re-seq #"[a-zA-Z]" "A(B%$c32d")
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't specify much as a input string however, a string IS A sequence, so you can filter out characters thus:

**EDIT: ASCII Solution/Refinement**

```
(filter #(<= 65 (int %) 132) "abZ9%xy") ; See NielsK's comment
```

Returns a lazy-sequence of characters.

Comment: Thank you Frank C for your help. Your Code outputs the numbers of the Alphabets, Not them themselves.

Comment: How can one implement the whole Alphabet range? (a - z and A -Z) Is there a function for this?

Comment: i did not downvote. this is a totally valid way to go. but the thing is, this gets you a list of ints. need to throw in a `map char` or something to convert back. also doesn't cover lower-case letters so just needs a 2nd range test too

Comment: `filter` already works like `map`, traversing a collection. <=> comparators can take multiple parameters. If you do the int cast in the filter function, the original item from the collection is returned. So `(filter #(<= 65 (int %) 132) "Abc%(AZz")` is probably what you wanted.